# recv function gives malformed data Winsock2 C++

Tags: tcp, recv, malformed

In my simple TCP client server application, server send repetitively 1 kB message to the client and client send a reply acknowledgement (just send 'ACK') for each packet. Just think this scenario like client and server passing 1 kB messages here and there in a infinite loop.

I send the same message every time and the fist byte (first char) is always 1. But while testing this client and server application in the same machine for a long time, I noticed first character of some of the received messages are something else in the receive buffer and `recv` function also returned 1024 (1 kB). This is not happen frequently.

This is the how I receive.

```
char recvBuff[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
int iResult = SOCKET_ERROR;
iResult = recv(curSocket, recvBuff, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
   return iResult;
}

if (recvBuff[0] != 1)
{
   //malformed receive
}

MessageHeader *q = (MessageHeader*)recvBuff;
message.header = *q; q++;
std::string temp((char*)q, message.header.fragmentSize);
message.message = temp;
```

Actually the problem is in constructing the temp string. It breaks since the correct fragment size not received. I tried to drop these kind of malformed data. But the problem is there is a gap between last successfully received fragment ID and first successfully received fragment ID after malformed receives. Any idea why these malformed receives happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re assuming that you’ve received a complete message when the `recv()` call completes.  If this is a TCP connection (as opposed to UDP), it is *byte-oriented*, and that means that `recv()` will return *whenever there are **any** bytes available*.

Put more explicitly, there is no reason that doing

```
send (toServerSocket, someMessage, 1024, 0);
```

on the client side will cause

```
recv (fromClientSocket, myBuffer, 1024, 0);
```

to receive 1,024 bytes.  It could just as well receive 27 bytes, with the remaining 997 coming from future calls to `recv()`.

What’s happening in your program, then, is that you’re getting one of these short returns, and it’s causing your program to lose sync. with the message stream.  How to fix it?  Use `recv()` to read enough of your message that you know the length (or set a fixed length, though that’s inefficient in many cases).  Then continue calling `recv()` into your buffer until you have read at least that many bytes.  *Note that you might read more bytes than the length of your message — that is, you may read some bytes that belong to the **next** message*, so you will need to keep those in the buffer after processing the current message.

Comment: hmm.. It seems you are right. I knew `send` and `recv` didn't guarantee complete sending and receiving. But I thought that 1024 bytes will be a possible size to send and receive completely. Seems to be I'm wrong. Yeah that what happen. That's why I loss the message header. thanks